# css z-index bug in blogger

Tags: css, z-index

I'm creating a new blogger template , but unfortunately I'm facing an issue.
simple example for what i am trying to do.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='slider'></div>
  <div class='posts'></div>
</div>
```

by default the second div (posts) should have z-index higher than the first one.
[see this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FJIFRD296JNH)
and see [this pic](https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-cOQ2QpRJJxE/WbmcbX-1RrI/AAAAAAAAFKI/-zJbmR8NyD8kR03_p6IWmh3FLHf_TfqDQCLcBGAs/s1600/Capture.PNG) and now see what should be done [here](https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-fdYC-4cTn9A/WbmcvCx54EI/AAAAAAAAFKM/DFM7DDh85D0vp6ipjGku75rP_9wBXSwfQCLcBGAs/s640/Capture.PNG)
, so what is the problem !.
here is my [blog](http://stylish-v4-2.blogspot.com)

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried already?

Comment: sorry , i forgot to attach my blog link.

Comment: you can see it now

Comment: Please do not link to external sites. Instead, try to boil your problem down into a minimal, concrete and verifiable example that can be posted as a code snippet in your question.

Comment: Not going to look on your blog, post relevant code here. Please read on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have an apparent higher `z-index`, the element must either be

1. After the other element or
2. Have a `position:relative;` or absolute when the previous element has a relative/absolute position.

```css
.d1{
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    background: tomato;
    position: relative;
}

.d2{
    width:80%;
    height:200px;
    background: blue;
    margin: -30px auto 0 auto;
    position: relative; /* Try removing this - it will be 'below' d1 because d1 has position:relative; */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='d1 slider'></div>
  <div class='d2 posts'></div>
</div>
```

In your case, this means adding `position:relative;` to `.container` class.

Comment: problem solved. thanks so much. god bless you my friend ^_^

Comment: No problem!  I notice you have asked quite a few questions, but have not accepted any of them.  To help others know when your question is solved and which answer best resolves it, you can click the gray checkmark beside that answer.  I recommend going through your old questions and doing that as well.